# How can i delete elements from an xml data

Tags: c#, xml

everyone i have a question on how to delete an block of elements from my xml file while knowing only the text value of one item inside it. There are hundreds of the the same blocks where the only difference is the ID values and the text that i know to delete the block.

```
public static void deleteBlock() {
        XElement xelement = XElement.Load(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tools\VisualStudioProjects\bausteine\modul.xml");
        foreach (XElement xEle in xelement.Descendants("SW.Blocks.CompileUnit"))
        {
            var complete = xEle;
            foreach(var item in xEle.Descendants("Text"))
 {
       if (item.Value=="The only thing i know to delete the Block") {
                    complete.Remove();
                }

        } complete.Save(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tools\VisualStudioProjects\modul.xml");
            }
```

I though i could look first for the element with the name SW.Blocks.CompileUnit then look inside it for the Text value and if it matches mine then it should delete the block and it should go through all blocks. It finds the block i want but deletes everything else and saves the block that i want to be deleted. Then it gives me Null Exception.

```
<SW.Blocks.CompileUnit ID="85" CompositionName="CompileUnits">
    <AttributeList> 
     <ObjectList>
      <MultilingualText ID="86" CompositionName="Comment">
        <ObjectList>
          <MultilingualTextItem ID="87" CompositionName="Items">
            <AttributeList>
              <Culture>de-DE</Culture>
              <Text />
            </AttributeList>
          </MultilingualTextItem>
        </ObjectList>
      </MultilingualText>
      <MultilingualText ID="88" CompositionName="Title">
        <ObjectList>
          <MultilingualTextItem ID="89" CompositionName="Items">
            <AttributeList>
              <Culture>de-DE</Culture>
              <Text>The Only thing i know to delete the Block</Text>
            </AttributeList>
          </MultilingualTextItem>
        </ObjectList>
      </MultilingualText>
    </ObjectList>
  </SW.Blocks.CompileUnit>
```

That is one of the blocks of the xml data. That is also the one that my codes leaves while deleting everything else. I hope i explained it a little better now. I dont know why its deleting everything else except the block and why is it giving me a null exception. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, ive added some code. There are like 100x of the same SW.Blocks and they only differ from each other by the ID or the Text name i put inside them. I want to go in my XML-File look for every element with the name SW.Blocks see if the text value matches the one with mine and if it does then delete the whole block.

Comment: If you use `Dim xe = ` and the XML snippet from the question, then `Dim noText = xe...<MultilingualText>.Where(Function(n) Not n...<Text>.Value = "Only thing i know to delete the Element")` will give you an IEnumerable of the `<<MultilingualText>` elements which do not have a `<Text`> element with that value.

Comment: While asking an question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and your code that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.

Comment: Did it can you reopen my question?

Answer (score 2):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication17
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement complete = doc.Descendants("SW.Blocks.CompileUnit").FirstOrDefault();
            complete.Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that's not quite what i was looking for. I need the code to look through the whole xml-file an look inside all sw.blocks.CompileUnit and see if the value in text is the same value i want to compare it with. If it is the same then it should delete the SW.Blocks.CompileUnit.

Comment: You can add a Where to filter :             List<XElement> complete = doc.Descendants("SW.Blocks.CompileUnit").Where(x => (string)x == "my text").ToList();

Comment: Thanks. Thats what im looking for :D